# "overriding" :initform setting in defclass for superclass (CLOS)

Tags: inheritance, common-lisp

I have a class defined with an :initform

```
(defclass A()
  ((MI :initarg :mi :initform (error "must specify mi") ) ) )
```

which comes with a initialize-instance :after method that computes some stuff (too long to show); the end result of this computation is relevant for both the class A and the derived class B; see below)

and a derived class

```
(defclass B(A)
  (( ABC :initarg :abc :initform (error "must specify abc") ) ) )
```

Now, the class B needs to do the same computation as A in its respective initialize-instance method; however, in this case the argument mi in A is a function of ABC in B.

So I tried to compute a "temporary mi" in B's initalize-instance; didn't work

I tried to compute mi, storing it in a local variable mitmp from B's ABC and called (call-next-method mitmp); didn't work

I tried to define another MI field within B without the :initform as in in A. I hoped that I would than be able compute mi within a let-form within B's initialize-instance; didn't work either.

[With a Blub language like C++ this would work; somehow I am stuck with this way of thinking.]

So I am left with the question "how can I have B to have a mandatory argument ABC that than is "transformed" into the mandatory A's mi and that given to A's initialize-instance.

Any hints are more than welcome.

[Edit: clarified some stuff]

Comment: If I write: `(defclass A () ((mi :initform (error "NO"))))` and `(defclass B () ((mi)))`, making an instance of A fails; making a B works. I suppose you could also use a `:default-initargs` option. But since you still have a problem, could you please make your code a little more self-contained  for others to test? Thanks

Comment: @coredump-: the comment by jkiiski solved the issue; the computation of mi from abc is rather involved, so I skipped that for the sake of brevity.

Comment: I am sure that @jkiiski would be grateful that you marked his answer as the accepted answer (check mark under the voting buttons) if you do find it acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a `:before` method on `b`s `initialize-instance`. If you use an `:after` method, it gets run only after `a` has already been initialized. A quick example:

```
(defclass a ()
  ((mi :initarg :mi :initform (error "Must specify mi"))
   (computed-value :accessor computed-value)))

(defmethod initialize-instance :after ((a a) &key)
  (with-slots (mi computed-value) a
    (setf computed-value (* mi 2))))

(defclass b (a)
  ((abc :initarg :abc :initform (error "must specify abc"))))

(defmethod initialize-instance :before ((b b) &key (abc 1 abc-p))
  ;; You have to check that ABC was given manually, since this is
  ;; run before initialising B. You wouldn't necessarily even 
  ;; need to have a slot for ABC if you don't need it for anything 
  ;; else.
  (unless abc-p (error "Must specify abc"))
  (setf (slot-value b 'mi) (+ abc 10)))

(computed-value (make-instance 'a :mi 4))
; => 8
(computed-value (make-instance 'b :abc 4))
; => 28
```

Comment: this solved basically the problem; thanks, I wasn't aware that I can use :before to override the ongoings in A's `initialize-instance`.